# Nestjs GraphQL query not running

Tags: graphql, apollo, graphql-js, nestjs

I have the following schema:

```
type User {
  id: String!
  email: String
}

type Mutation {
  createUser(input: CreateUserDto!): CreateUserResponseDto!
}

type Query {
  user(id: Int!): User
}

input CreateUserDto {
  email: String!
  password: String!
}

type CreateUserResponseDto {
  id: String!
}
```

And I have the following resolver:

```
import {Args, Mutation, Resolver} from '@nestjs/graphql';
import {UserService} from '../service/user.service';
import {CreateUserDto, CreateUserResponseDto, UserDto} from '../controller/dto/user.dto';
import {Query} from '@nestjs/common';

@Resolver('User')
export class UserResolver {

  constructor(private readonly userService: UserService) {
  }

  @Mutation()
  async createUser(@Args('input') userDto: CreateUserDto): Promise<CreateUserResponseDto> {
    const userEntity = await this.userService.createUser(userDto);

    return {
      id: userEntity.id,
    };
  }

  @Query('user')
  async getUser(@Args('id') id: number): Promise<UserDto> {
    const userEntity = await this.userService.findUserById(id);

    return {
      id: userEntity.id,
      email: userEntity.email,
    };
  }
}
```

When running the following query:

```
{
  user(id: 2) {
    email
  }
}
```

I am getting the following response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "user": null
  }
}
```

And when trying to debug it seems like the call never reaches the resolver.

When trying to run the mutation, all works as expected.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong `Query` decorator. You've imported it from `@nestjs/common` instead of `@nestjs/graphql`.

It's confusing that they both have the same name and if you're using your IDE to automatically fix imports for you it's possible to pull in the wrong one.